# Spigot permission node for specific functions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, server-administration, minecraft-spigot

If I want to give a certain group of people permission to run functions in a specific directory, for example:

```
world/data/functions/custom/admin <-- functions for admins
world/data/functions/custom/moderator <-- functions for mods
```

what is the permission node to assign to a group? I assumed it would be:

```
function.custom:moderator
```

but that doesn't work. This permissions plugin is Permissions EX (PEX) which follows the standard syntax of any permissions plugin such as Essentials for Bukkit.

Comment: Stack Exchange usage tip: When you add tags, the people who follow those tags are notified, that way you get the attention of the right experts. In this case, 33 people follow "mods", 16 follow "minecraft-mods", 15 "server-administration and 7 "minecraft-spigot". 1600 people follow "minecraft", but they also get a lot more questions and are likely to ignore most.